# How to prevent direct access of HTML page present in tomcat server

Tags: tomcat

I have a war file with name **REGENTS**  and i am using Apache Tomcat 7

Inside the war file there are 4 HTML pages as shown

```
login.html 

reset_password.html 

management.html 

sales.html
```

The issue i am facing is how can i prevent direct access to HTML pages other than **login.html**

How can i prevent the direct access of HTML pages

For example   If the user types the direct URL as shown below , how can i redirerct him to **login.html**

```
http://localhost:8080/REGENTS/dealer/sales.html
```

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ivlTPzd-8eo is about security-constraints but in german

Comment: You should google tomcat filters or tomcat valves.